# View sticking outside of a FrameLayout doesn't intercept touch events

Tags: android

I have a thumbnail of the last image taken by the camera at the bottom left-hand side of my screen.
At its upper left corner, I have a X button to delete the last image taken by the camera.

When I try pressing that button, nothing happens, unless I press its bottom right corner, the one that is still within the bounds of where it is originally meant to be:

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clipChildren="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/gallery"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/open_gallery"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/deleteLastImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-22dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/delete_last_image"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I worked around it by not using negative margins, but place the `ImageView` outside of the `FrameLayout` like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gallery"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/open_gallery"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/deleteLastImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/delete_last_image"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```